# Javascript Averages

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to learn Javascript.  I've built the following code to find the average from an array of numbers.  It works *except* the last returned value is always NaN.  I cannot figure out why.  If I move this piece outside of the block it seems to forget altogether what the variable sum is supposed to be equal to.  Is there some kind of global-variable type equivalent I'm supposed to be using for JS?

```
var average = function(myarray) {
    sum = 0;
    for (counter = 0; counter <= myarray.length; counter++) {
        sum = sum + myarray[counter];
        average = sum / myarray.length;
        console.log(average);
    };
}

average([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: You have `<= myarray.length`, but the last value is one less than the length, so switch to `< myarray.length`

Comment: Should also put the computation of the average AFTER the end of the `for` loop because it only needs to be calculated once.

Comment: Also, `sum / myarray.length` will not be an average, `sum / (counter + 1)` is (if you're after running average). If you want just the total average, @jfriend00 is your friend.

Comment: And, you're trying to assign the average to your function.  I'm guessing you should be returning the averaage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
counter <= myarray.length
```

to

```
counter < myarray.length
```

because indexes start at 0.

Full example:

```
var average = function(myarray) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var counter = 0; counter < myarray.length; counter++) {
    sum += myarray[counter];
   }

   return sum / myarray.length;
}

console.log(average([1,2,3]));
```

**JSBin Demo: http://jsbin.com/siyugi/1/edit**

Comment: The best answers use words to describe what was changed and why.  Could also just use `.reduce()` on the array.

Answer (score 1):

`myarray[myarray.length]` is `undefined`, which intoxicates your computation with `NaN`(Not A Number).

Just change it to

```
for(counter = 0; counter < myarray.length; counter ++) {
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just learning you should know it is good practice to not use .length in a for loop like that. It causes the code to have to check the length of your array on each loop. And remember that .length is returning the number of elements in the array; but array index starts at 0.

```
for(var counter = 0, length = myarray.length; counter < length; counter++){
}
```

Would be the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use variables without declaring them with `var` keyword, otherwise they will become global properties.
2. The JavaScript Arrays are zero index based arrays. So, if the size of the array is 3, then the first element will be accessed with 0 and the last with 2. JavaScript is very forgiving, so when you access an element at an invalid index in the array, it will simply return `undefined`.
3. In the iteration, you are replacing the current function object with the `average` value. So, subsequent calls to `average` will fail, since `average` is not a function object any more.
4. It is a good practice to have a function return the computed value, instead of printing the value, so that it will not violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

In your case,

```
for (counter = 0; counter <= myarray.length; counter++) {
```

The `counter` runs till the last index of the array + 1. Since it returns `undefined` in the last iteration, JavaScript returns `NaN` in the arithmetic operation.

```
console.log(1 + undefined);
# NaN
```

So, you need to change the code, like this

```
function Average(myarray) {
    var sum = 0, counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < myarray.length; counter++) {
        sum = sum + myarray[counter];
    }
    return sum / myarray.length;
}
```

If you are interested, you can compute the sum with [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), like this

```
function Average(myarray) {
    var sum = 0;
    myarray.forEach(function(currentNumber) {
        sum += currentNumber;
    });
    return sum / myarray.length;
}
```

Even better, you can calculate the sum with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), like this

```
function Average(myarray) {
    return myarray.reduce(function(sum, currentNumber) {
        return sum + currentNumber;
    }, 0) / myarray.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the average of an array of numbers as follows:

```
var avg = c => c.reduce((a,b) => a +b) / c.length;
avg([1,2,3])
```